# Create Change Listeners for Various Databases in Java

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

I have a requirement where I want to register listeners to listen for change on a database (depending upon the client's preference, it can be any RDBMS), and to fire some Java code if any change has occurred. These changes may directly occur on the Database itself, and not necessarily use a JPA Repository. Hence, the Entity Listener option isn't a useful one. Having a thread constantly running to poll the database sounds like a very expensive method and one that uses a lot of resources. So I need some help in figuring out the best way to go about creating some sort of a Listener that may respond to changes in a database as and when it comes.

Comment: The answer strictly depends on the database. There is no general solution to this. For example in case of Mongo, you can read oplog file or use capped collection, tailable cursors to do this.

Comment: Postgres and Oracle have features to notify clients of changes, but I am not aware of anything similar in other databases. So I would say there is no way you will get an efficient implementation that is DBMS independent ("DBMS independent" is a nice way of saying "runs equally slow on all platforms")